# Routing issue - Wifi to LAN

Tags: raspbian, wifi, raspbian-stretch, ethernet-port, web-interface

The plan is to be able to connect to the wifi home network and connect a Cat5 to the eth0 port. Then connect the Cat5 to a pc. I then want to be able to connect to the pc via RDP from the internet using the pi wifi as access.

So far i have tried teamviewering into the pi which worked but couldnt get access to the pc on eth0

Anyone got any tips??
Many thanks
Mark

Comment: Forget RDP (& XRDP), use RealVNC.

Comment: Cheers Dougie but unfortunately the scenario i'm planning is to be able to have multiple sessions which i dont think realvnc offers.

Comment: RealVNC gives you five cloud sessions for free. If you don't use the cloud support you can run as many as you like. I just ran up 10 sessions to ten different raspberries with no struggles.

Comment: This won't be simple - you'll need something like dnsmasq, and the realisation that you'll be double-NATing to the PC